# iOS Mail app archive button sometimes goes back to inbox view?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, gmail

Normally pressing "archive" brings me to the next email but occasionally it brings me back to the inbox. Is this just a bug?

I'm using my gmail account and I'm in the "all inboxes" view. My OS is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer having this issue...